# Laravel - upload image

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload a file to a location but it create always a folder with the file name and put the file inside this folder.

For exemple: If we add a file name `xpto.pdf` it put the file into `/location/xpto.pdf/xpto.pdf` and i don't understand why it happens.

```
$directory = "\\SRVGDOC\GDOC\CSdefault21\group1\";
$fname = pathinfo(Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$fext = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fullname = $directory . $fname . '.' . $fext;
// $fullname = \\SRVGDOC\GDOC\CSdefault21\group1\xpto.pdf

Input::file('file')->move($fullname, $fname.'.'.$fext);
```

What can be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: did you notice.. `$fullname = $directory . $fname . '.' . $fext;` and then `->move($fullname, $fname.'.'.$fext);`?

Comment: $fullname = $directory . $fname ;

Comment: So, i have just to put $fullname = $directory and then move($fullname, $fname. '.'.$fext); @BagusTesa

Comment: why without $fext @BilalAhmed

Answer (score 1):

The **move** method requires the path (directory name) and the filename.