# Laravel - Could not move the file

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file but, I getting this error : `Could not move the file`.

My code:

```
$directory = "C:\bck\";
$fname = pathinfo(Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$fext = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fullname = $directory;
Input::file('file')->move($fullname, $fname);
```

Error:

```
Could not move the file "C:\xampp\tmp\php6D32.tmp" to "C:\bck\aaaa" ()
```

if i put `$fullname = $directory . $fname . '.' . $fext;` it create a folder inside `\bck\` with the file name and put the file inside this new folder. But i don't want to create a folder with the file name.

Thank you

Comment: What's `$directory`?

Comment: Is the PHP user allowed to access that directory? (`"C:\bck\aaaa"`).

Comment: Updated @QuỳnhNguyễn

Comment: I update the question. If it creates a folder and file inside folder if i change the code i think that is not a permission issue. @TobiasF.

Comment: Please post your exact code, as it is now this will produce at least 4 errors (3 times `'undefined variable'` and one time `'expected "'`).

Comment: You probably should migrate away from XAMPP to virtual-machine based server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997926/laravel-upload-image)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `$directory = "C:\your_project\public\uploads";`

And Setting your `uploads` folder have write permission

[image]

---

Or you can try this way. Edit your disk at: `config/filesystems.php`

```
'disks' => [
    'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
    ],
    'custom' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'root'   => 'c:/bck',
    ]
]
```

And handle at your Controller

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request) {
    $data   = $request->all();
    $fileUpload = $data['file'];
    $originalFileName = $fileName->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::disk('uploads')->put($originalFileName, file_get_contents($fileUpload));
}

public function customUploadFile(Request $request) {
    $data   = $request->all();
    $fileUpload = $data['file'];
    $originalFileName = $fileName->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::disk('custom')->put($originalFileName, file_get_contents($fileUpload));
}
```

Comment: @user3242861 I've updated my answer. Please check and try that way.

Comment: but this is creating only also create a folder @QuỳnhNguyễn

Comment: @user3242861 You want create new directory for that upload file?

Comment: @user3242861 So please tell me what's do you want to handle Upload directory?

Comment: for example: we have the file xpto.pdf and $directory is c:\bck\ . So i want to put the file inside this directory. Just it! @QuỳnhNguyễn

Comment: @user3242861 So please check `customUploadFile` at newest answer. And edit in your `disks` follow my answer.