# Laravel - How can i use copy() instead move()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problems with uploading files with move(), so i want to try with copy().

How copy() works?

I try this:

```
File::copy(Input::file('file'), $dest);
```

but i have this error:

```
copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory
```

Comment: Yes? It can't be a directory. What is the problem? You need to add a filename to copy to.

Comment: What kind of problems you have with move()? copy() needs a destination path, including the filename ("cannot be a directory"...) like `/var/www/app.com/public/media/filename.jpg`

Comment: My problem is this and i don't know what to do more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002030/laravel-could-not-move-the-file#44002234 @Alex

Answer (score 3):

As the error indicates the second parameter couldn't be a directory. It should be a file name instead. As an example,

```
File::copy(Input::file('file'), 'new/location/file.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory - this line suggests that functions second argument is a directory, it should be a file name instead of directory.

it should be like something

```
$dest = "text.php";
File::copy(Input::file('file'), $dest);
```